# Expectation of function with random delay

Tags: probability, expectation

Given a continuous function $r(t) \geq 0$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, what is $\mathbb{E}[r(t-X)]$ where $X \geq 0$ is a continuous random variable with PDF $f(x)$?

I am thinking that since $r(t)$ is continuous, $\mathbb{E}[r(t-X)] = r(d)$ for some $d \in (-\infty,t]$. Intuitively, I might expect $d = \mathbb{E}[X]$ such that $\mathbb{E}[r(t-X)] = r(t-\mathbb{E}[X])$. Is my reasoning completely wrong? If not, how could I prove this?

Comment: You can push an expectation through a function if the function is linear.  But you are not told that $r$ is linear.  So, you need to use the general formula $E[h(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x)f_X(x)dx$.  [Note: Continuity of the $r(\cdot)$ function has very little to do with this problem, likely it is only assumed to ensure the integral is well defined.]

Comment: However, a major problem with this question is that $r(t)$ seems to only be defined for $t \geq 0$, which means $r(t-X)$ may not even be defined (if $X>t$).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know the general formula, but I can't do much with it because I don't know what $r(t)$ is. This is not a hw problem. I encountered it in my research. I want to know what is the interpretation of the quantity $\mathbb{E}[r(t-X)]$ and whether I can think of it as a delayed version of $r(t)$.

Comment: Note that the general formula for $E[h(X)]$ that I gave above was written precisely, without knowing the $h(\cdot)$ function (so that is not an issue).  Since $E[r(t-X)]$ is an averaging of $r$ values, it will be between the max and min values of the continuous $r()$ function and, by the intermediate value theorem, there will of course be particular $x$ values for which $f(x)=E[r(t-X)]$.  This of course assumes $X \in [0,t]$ with prob 1, else $r(t-X)$ is not defined.

Comment: Thanks again. If I was to assume that $r(t)$ is continuously increasing, such that there is some x for which $r(t-x)=\mathbb{E}[r(t-X)]$, is there any approach I could take in order to compute x or its mean?